# A question about multiplier algebra of $C_0(G)\otimes C_b(G)$ for a locally compact group $G$

Tags: schur-multipliers, harmonic-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

Let $G$ be locally compact group. How we can show that
$$
M(C_0(G)\otimes C_b(G))=C_b(G,C_b(G)).
$$
($M(C_0(G)\otimes C_b(G))$ is the multiplier algebra of $C_0(G)\otimes C_b(G)$)

Comment: Which part can't you show? (Also, the fact $G$ is a group seems to play no role in what you want to prove.)

Comment: I do not know how to define a bijection between them.

Comment: I can define a map from $_M(C0(G) \otimes C_b(G))$ to $C_b(G,C_b(G))$ but I can not show that the map is sujective. by the way, you are right, I do not need to assume $G$ is a group.

Comment: Try defining a map that goes the other way from right hand side to left hand side?

Comment: yes but I couldnt


Comment: would you please introduce a reference to me?


Comment: You should know, or be able to *work out for yourself*, how a bounded continuous function defines a multiplier of the algebra of $C_0$ functions